# How to re-position UILabel in the exact same position as another UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I'm trying to re-position a UILabel exactly over another UILabel (identical position). Its not positioning itself exactly over the target UILabel.

See code below

```
let element1yPosition = element1.frame.origin.y. // Element 1 y Position

let element2yPosition = element2.frame.origin.y. // Element 2 y Position

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

    element1.frame.origin.y = element2yPosition     // Repositioning stage. 
                                                   //Fails because Element 1 doesn't re-position itself in the exact same position as Element 2 as required.

})
```

Comment: Change element1.frame not the origin

Comment: Use `autolayout`.

Comment: add this `self.element1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and after that change the frame using `element1.frame = element2.frame`

Comment: Don't forget to use `layoutIfNeeded()` when updating layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

   element1.frame = element2.frame 

})
```

Answer (score -1):

element1.frame.origin.y is a number in struct. element1 didn't know his's frame.origin.y changed.
if You want to change a UIView's position, you should change it's frame,center,transform.

In Objective-C, it's wrong.[image]

That's the right way: 
[image]